# Question about Optional chaining and Nullish coalescing JavaScript operators support in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, ide, phpstorm, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

I wanted to ask if anyone knows how one can support the JavaScript nullish coalescing operator (`??`) and the optional chaining operator (`?.`) in PhpStorm.

Currently I am developing a project in react-native in PhpStorm, both operators work fine but PhpStorm sets an `expression expected` error and all files using these operators become error underlined.

How can I add support for these features so the IDE is happy?

Comment: Can you verify that PhpStorm is using the correct ES-version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Nullish Coalescing support was implemented more than a year ago,  see [WEB-32660](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32660).
Please make sure that you are using the most recent IDE version and that the **JavaScript language version** is set to *ECMAScript 6* or *React JSX* in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**